# Can't access Database Settings in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server

Help! I needed to add a default backup location for my local DB, but for some reason I cannot access "Database Settings in SSMS." When I select it, I get the following error:

> Property MasterDBPath is not available for Information 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Information'. This property may not exist for this object, or may not be retrievable due to insufficient access rights.

I added `BackupDirectory` string through Regedit, but when I try to restore a database from a file, I get the same error.

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/23609/sql-server-localdb-instance-error-restoring-backup-masterdbpath-not-available

Comment: That did help. Thank you!